# Whitespace in memoir titles

Tags: spacing, memoir, sectioning

I am unhappy about the whitespace before and after my chapters, sections, and subsections etc.

Using the `memoir` class I tried to find out on how to reduce this.

For my chapters it says I should use the `\beforechapskip` and `\afterchapskip` commands. For my sections `\setbeforeSskip` and `afterskip` (i think).

This must be very stupid, but I tried to change these but I must be doing it wrong. In this example

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setbeforeSskip{1ex}
\setafterSskip{1ex}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

I get this error: `! Undefined control sequence.` Like I said, it's probably easy but im just not very good at these things and i have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Could anyone provide me a small example of how to set the whitespace for chapters and sections etc?

Comment: @Herbert, @Alan: Three answers from different persons within 26 seconds is not too bad. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `memoir` manual section 6.6:

> In the following I will use S to stand
>   for one of sec, subsec, subsubsec,
>   para or subpara, which are in turn
>   shorthand for section through to
>   subparagraph, as summarised in Table
>   6.3.
>
> ```
> \setbeforeSskip{<skip>}
> ```
>
> Table 6.3: Values for S in section
>   styling macro names.
>
> sec  subsec  subsubsec   para    subpara

So you need to replace S with the appropriate value: (for sections, `sec`):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setbeforesecskip{1ex}
\setaftersecskip{1ex}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

There are a number of other places where the `memoir` manual uses this kind of scheme; it often trips people up.

Comment: If you add the page number (and possibly the enclosed code snippet) to your quote, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @lockstep.  I added a reference to the section instead of a page number.  In my memman the relevant page is p. 100.  Not sure why the discrepancy.

Comment: Gosh i feel SO stupid now, thx folks!

Comment: Don't feel stupid: because (1) memoir, though excellent, has some obscure bits like the way it explains what you tripped over; and (2) the only stupid questions are the ones you don't ask because you feel shy...

Answer (score 1):

you have to replace the S with `sec`, `subsec` aso.
eg:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setbeforesecskip{1ex}
\setaftersecskip{1ex}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```